# Cannot update to more than 1 Basic size dynos per process type

Tags: heroku

I went to scale an app, but when I follow [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#scaling-from-the-cli) for doing so:

```
heroku ps:scale web=2
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Cannot update to more than 1 Basic size dynos per process type.
```

I see the message, but I want more *web* dynos (not a worker dyno).

Based on the docs, this should be straight forward. Why won't it scale?

Answer (score 0):

From [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling):

> Heroku apps can be scaled to run on multiple dynos simultaneously (**except on Eco or Basic dynos**).

So you need to change from 'Basic' ($7/dyno/month) to at least 'Standard' ($25-$500/dyno/month) in order to be able to scale the application.

This is also indicated in the description of 'Basic' in the 'Dyno Types' image:

[image]

> **Basic** - Perfect for small-scale personal projects and apps that don't need scaling.